# Adding new subitem to already exsisting item

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Hello I want to add a new subitem in a listView

> listView.Items[0].SubItems.Add(textBox.Text);

I clip it under a button, but when I click that button, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

It works in Delphi :D

Full code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listView1.Items[0].SubItems.Add(textBox1.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Lloyd I guess that WPF means Windows Phone Forms? I use Windows Forms Application.

Comment: @Dudi WPF stays for Windows Presentation Foundation

Comment: Post the full code in the Button click Event Handler. WPF and XAML is basically like an upgrade to Windows Forms, not a replacement tho, and allows more dynamic content 3D rendering etc, Windows Phone 7 using a subset of WPF XAML.

Comment: try ListViewItem item = listView1.Items[0]; if ((item != null) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))) item.SubItems.Add(textBox1.Text);

Comment: @Lloyd Nothing happened. But even if I use `listView1.Items[0].SubItems.Add("test");` still nothing.

Comment: call listView1.Update();

Comment: Nothing, but listView1.Items.Add(textBox1.text); Works, but this isn't subitem

Comment: What is the value of `listView1.View`?
The subitems may be present but not visible, depending on the mode.

Comment: listView1.View =  list, I add subitems in property and they are not shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably not enough columns. You need one column for the main item entry plus one column per subitem. Surplus subitems will not be displayed.

```
var columnHeader = new ColumnHeader { Text = "Name", Width = 100 };
listView1.Columns.Add(columnHeader);
```

You can add the columns in the designer as well.

---

Note: Subitems are only displayed in the `Details` `View`. This is a table like view type. You can set it in the designer in the properties window under "Appearance" / "View", in the task pane (see picture) or with code

```
listView1.View = View.Details;
```

[image]

Comment: There is anyway to display subitems?

Comment: You must change the view type to `listView1.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;`

Comment: I'm doing that, but I've got blank page. Maybe I should somehow define for wich item I want see details?

Comment: No. The view type is a global setting of the listview. You can also add items, subitems and columns in the designer. Play around in the designer until you understand how it works, before doing it by code. The main item is diplayed in the first column, the first subitem in the second column, the second subitem in the third column, and so on.